# EmberJS 2.13 unit testing: wrapping synchronous code in a run loop?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-testing

This is repeated a few times in the current Ember documentation, so I feel like I must be missing something. Let's take the [simplest example I found](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/testing/testing-models/).

Why is the call to levelUp considered asynchronous to warrant wrapping it in the run loop?
[incrementProperty](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/299c1ab3d804fd92b0ec9b9c2e7a1fa100335753/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L428) is synchronous, and as far as I can tell, so is [set](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ee8ab348484421f254fe995c6f04f0d4a0859cfa/packages/ember-metal/lib/property_set.js#L18) (but I could be mistaken here)

player.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  level:     DS.attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),
  levelName: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'Noob' }),

  levelUp() {
    let newLevel = this.incrementProperty('level');
    if (newLevel === 5) {
      this.set('levelName', 'Professional');
    }
  }
});
```

player-test.js

```
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';

moduleForModel('player', 'Unit | Model | player', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: []
});

test('should increment level when told to', function(assert) {
  // this.subject aliases the createRecord method on the model
  const player = this.subject({ level: 4 });

  // wrap asynchronous call in run loop
  Ember.run(() => player.levelUp());

  assert.equal(player.get('level'), 5, 'level gets incremented');
  assert.equal(player.get('levelName'), 'Professional', 'new level is called professional');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are absolutely right. It is not well-described anywhere in the guides.

In testing mode, autorun is disabled. You can read further from [the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/applications/run-loop/#toc_how-is-run-loop-behaviour-different-when-testing) about this.

**But *changing the value in model* triggers a run-loop.** You can see that at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/768b7949d2d1f6860aff492c342b0729?openFiles=tests.unit.models.player-test.js%2C). The result is:

> Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the
>   run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous
>   side-effects in a run

(By the way, both `set` and `incrementProperty` trigger this run-loop as your guess.)

Then here is the run loop source:

1. `DS.attr` returns a [computed property with set](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.13.0/addon/attr.js#L137).
2. The `set` function [triggers an event](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.13.0/addon/attr.js#L162).
3. At the end, [a run loop is triggered](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.12.1/addon/-private/system/model/internal-model.js#L861).

Comment: I think you meant to say that in testing **autoruns** are disabled, not the run loop itself! The confusing part to me was knowing what to wrap in a run loop during testing. In production, you wrap any non-Ember async callbacks in a run loop, while Ember async callsbacks (like _set_) do not need to be wrapped. This is all fine and dandy, for production. When it comes to testing, the non-Ember async callbacks need no modification since they don't trigger an autorun. Only Ember async callbacks need to be wrapped in a run loop when testing. This is the part that the guides are missing IMO.

Comment: Yes, **autoruns** are disabled. You are right, guides are missing that part. [This post](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-ember-run-loop) is old but good. Actually, most of the time you don't need that but for ember model tests, you need that.

Answer (score 1):

@ykaragol is absolutely right about his explanation within his correct answer and I have nothing to add why you need to wrap your code within a run loop; because the source code is there and `emberRun.schedule` is being called, which requires a run-loop.

What I would like to explain is a bit more about the assertion error you get: "You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run". That does not directly mean an asynchronous operation (in the sense that an ajax call is made, or a timer is triggered) is in place. We are mostly unaware but; Ember.js does use `Ember.run` loops and various run queues such as `sync`, `actions`, `render`, `afterRender`, etc. in order to schedule the effects of our codes so as to optimize the rendering of our application. Even if the code `this.set('levelName', 'Professional');` does seem like pretty synchronous; Ember wraps it within a run-loop so that the computed property calculation, or other updates are buffered together in order to prevent multiple rendering (hence decreased performance) of the templates.

I only wished there was better explanation about both run loop, run queues, or how and why to use run loops within tests, but there is not :(

Comment: Agreed. The guides are pretty expansive on all these topics, and it has all sank in much better after a second read. I think they key part that is currently missing in the guides is an explanation of why Ember async callbacks do not need to be wrapped in a explicit run loop during production, which is what creating this need to wrap them in an explicit run loop during testing. Contrast this to non-Ember async callbacks, where the guidance is to wrap them in a run loop during production, and nothing changes for testing.